# Error : NG0204 with no specific details after Angular upgrade from 15 to 16

Tags: javascript, angular, angular15, angular16, angular-upgrade

I have been working on this task to upgrade from angular 15 to 16. After upgrading to 16 I am seeing this Error: NG0204 error in the console on serving my app. No additional information is provided (see image attached)
[image]

Any idea what this could be related to?

I have tried debugging but couldn't understand whats going on here since theres no additional details in the error.

Comment: This is a prod build, run a dev build will give your more info on the error

Comment: Thankyou https://stackoverflow.com/users/884123/matthieu-riegler, but i am getting this error on ng serve not on ng build.  Kindly help

Comment: You have optimization enabled on your dev build. You should disable them !